# Time series with a sequence of zeros

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I am trying to model a time series that contains a sequence of zeros. I tried fitting an ARIMA model using `auto.arima` function from the forecast package in R but the MAPE is reported as infinity (probably due to division by zero). Moreover, the `auto.arima` fits an ARIMA(0,1,0) model over the data.

Can you suggest any types of models that may be appropriate for such data?

Comment: I am curious what that data represents. Could you give us a little background information? I agree that MAPE may be zero because of division by zero.

Comment: Such series can be found in hydrology and meteorology. For example we may have 0 precipitation for several hours or 0 temperature for several hours or no sales (business application) for several days etc.

Comment: @RichardHardy Such a time series could also be representative of interest rate data that has hit the zero lower bound.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I was not interested in the general case but in this particular one so as to get a better idea of modelling choices that are relevant to this particular question.

Comment: @RichardHardy I am applying it to precipitation and temperature series.  Both values have zeros as described in the question.

Answer (score 1):

A common approach to handle many zeroes in a time series is to use a [Croston Model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127337/explain-the-croston-method-of-r).  To implement this model with your time series there are two R packages [forecast](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/index.html) and [tsintermittent](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tsintermittent/index.html). The tsintermittent package optimizes the Croston model $\alpha$ parameter whereas the forecast package produces a forecast for a given $\alpha$ value.

This is not the only approach to forecasting a time series w/ a sequence of zeroes but is a common approach. Another approach would be to fit a zero-inflated or hurdle model.

However, as mentioned in the comments of the post by the OP, the measurements could be continuous on the positive half-line. With non-negative measurements and a zero point mass the most likely approach would be a Tweedie regression. Here is a good post from SO with example codes: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21807118/r-codes-for-tweedie-compound-poisson-gamma

Comment: Tweedie distribution doesn't seems a proper tool to forecast a seasonal time series for me . Could you mind to make more explanation ?

Comment: LSTM is not able to process timeseries with lots of 0s please?